# slicing a URL ready for get ip by host name

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to slice the URL in this code and if URL[2] first 4 characters are www. just add it to the new list but if they are not www. then URL = www. + URL. The problem I am having is I keep getting results like www.www.google.com. I have tried loads of different expressions and can't get this right> Please help: )

```
 for i in raw_links:
        raw_links += (scrape_links(i))
        checked += 1
        string = str(checked) + ' links checked'
        print(string)

        for i in raw_links:
            i = i.split('//') and i.split('/')
            url = i[2]
            del i

            if url[0:3] != 'www.':
                top_domain = 'www.' + url
                if not top_domain in checked_links:
                    checked_links += top_domain
                    print(top_domain)
            elif url[0:3] == 'www.':
                checked_links += url
                print(url)
            else:
                del i
                print(raw_links[i],'deleted!!')
```

Comment: use urllib's urljoin function

Comment: How would I do that and where? I am a beginner so please be more precise if you can :)

Comment: please ignore that. I have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for misleading in comment. All you have to do is to change the if condition as below.

```
if not url.startswith('www.'):
    url = 'www.'+url
```

This will work for sure. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
if url[0:3] != 'www.':
```

Will always trigger because url[0:3] will only return the first three characters which will never equal 'www.' Therefore your url's already starting with www. will still have www. added to them.

```
if url[0:3] == 'www.':
```

Will never trigger (since it returns only 3 characters 'www') so good url's starting with 'www.' will not be added to your list.